# adding a load more posts button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, button, infinite-scroll

I want to add a simple load more button to the front page of my wordpress site that will load more posts.  I'm using a query and bootstrap to have 1 post per line, and then 2, and then 1, and so on.  I want 15 posts to be displayed and then a load more button, and then when you press the button 15 more posts are loaded.  I've started to try to add this button, but every time I try it does not work.  I have tried plugins and making my own.  If anyone can help me add in a load more button I would be extremely appreciative.

my front-page.php

```html
<?php 
/* 
* Template Name: 
*/ 

get_header(); 
get_template_part ('inc/carousel'); 

$the_query = new WP_Query( [ 
'posts_per_page' => 15, 
'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1) 
] ); 

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { ?> 
<div id="ajax"> 
<?php 
$i = 0; 
$j = 0; 
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { $the_query->the_post(); 

if ( $i % 5 === 0 ) { // Large post: on the first iteration and every 7th post after... ?> 
<div class="row"> 
<article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-12 col-md-12' ); ?>> 
<div class="large-front-container"> 
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'large-front-thumbnail')); ?> 
</div> 
<div class="front-page-date"><?php echo str_replace('mins', 'minutes', human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'); ?></div>
<h2><a class="front-page-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 
<p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p> 
<div class="front-page-post-info"> 
<a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a> 
<?php get_template_part( 'front-shop-the-post' ); ?> 
<?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?> 
<div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div> 
</div> 
</article> 
</div> 

<?php 

} else { // Small posts ?> 
<?php if($j % 2 === 0) echo '<div class="row">'; ?> 
<article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-6 col-md-6' ); ?>> 
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'medium-front-thumbnail')); ?> 
<div class="front-page-date"><?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?></div>
<h2><a class="front-page-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 
<p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p> 
<div class="front-page-post-info"> 
<a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
<?php get_template_part( 'front-shop-the-post' ); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
    <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div> 
    </div>

</article> 

<?php $j++; if($j % 2 === 0) echo '</div>'; ?> 
<?php 
} 
$i++; 
}?> 

</div> 
<?php if(get_query_var('paged') < $the_query->max_num_pages) { 
} 
} 
elseif (!get_query_var('paged') || get_query_var('paged') == '1') { 
echo '<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>'; 
} 
get_footer();
```

EDITS FROM DOMINIQUE'S ANSWER

front-page.php

```html
<?php 
/* 
* Template Name: 
*/ 

get_header(); 
get_template_part ('inc/carousel'); 

$the_query = new WP_Query( [ 
'posts_per_page' => 15, 
'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1) 
] ); 

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { ?> 
<div id="ajax"> 
<?php 
$i = 0; 
$j = 0; 
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { $the_query->the_post(); 

if ( $i % 5 === 0 ) { // Large post: on the first iteration and every 7th post after... ?> 
<div class="row"> 
<article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-12 col-md-12' ); ?>> 
<div class="large-front-container"> 
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'large-front-thumbnail')); ?> 
</div> 
<div class="front-page-date"><?php echo str_replace('mins', 'minutes', human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'); ?></div>
<h2><a class="front-page-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 
<p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p> 
<div class="front-page-post-info"> 
<a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a> 
<?php get_template_part( 'front-shop-the-post' ); ?> 
<?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?> 
<div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div> 
</div> 
</article> 
</div> 

<?php 

} else { // Small posts ?> 
<?php if($j % 2 === 0) echo '<div class="row">'; ?> 
<article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-6 col-md-6' ); ?>> 
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'medium-front-thumbnail')); ?> 
<div class="front-page-date"><?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?></div>
<h2><a class="front-page-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 
<p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p> 
<div class="front-page-post-info"> 
<a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
<?php get_template_part( 'front-shop-the-post' ); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
    <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div> 
    </div>

</article> 

<?php $j++; if($j % 2 === 0) echo '</div>'; ?> 
<?php 
} 
$i++; 
}?> 

</div> 
<?php if(get_query_var('paged') < $the_query->max_num_pages) { ?>
    <button id=load-more>load more</button>
<?php
} 
} 
elseif (!get_query_var('paged') || get_query_var('paged') == '1') { 
echo '<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>'; 
} 
get_footer();
```

loop.php

```html
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
          $the_query->the_post();
<?php 
$i = 0; 
$j = 0; 
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { $the_query->the_post(); 

if ( $i % 5 === 0 ) { // Large post: on the first iteration and every 7th post after... ?> 
<div class="row"> 
<article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-12 col-md-12' ); ?>> 
<div class="large-front-container"> 
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'large-front-thumbnail')); ?> 
</div> 
<div class="front-page-date"><?php echo str_replace('mins', 'minutes', human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'); ?></div>
<h2><a class="front-page-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 
<p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p> 
<div class="front-page-post-info"> 
<a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a> 
<?php get_template_part( 'front-shop-the-post' ); ?> 
<?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?> 
<div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div> 
</div> 
</article> 
</div> 

<?php 

} else { // Small posts ?> 
<?php if($j % 2 === 0) echo '<div class="row">'; ?> 
<article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-6 col-md-6' ); ?>> 
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'medium-front-thumbnail')); ?> 
<div class="front-page-date"><?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?></div>
<h2><a class="front-page-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 
<p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p> 
<div class="front-page-post-info"> 
<a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
<?php get_template_part( 'front-shop-the-post' ); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
    <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div> 
    </div>

</article> 

<?php $j++; if($j % 2 === 0) echo '</div>'; ?> 
<?php 
} 
$i++; 
}?>  
        }
?>
```

functions.php

```html
//LOAD MORE
   add_action( 'wp_ajax_load_more', 'load_more' );

  function load_more() {
    if ( isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === 'load_more' ){
      $loopFile        = $_POST['loop_file'];
      $paged           = $_POST['page_no'];
      $posts_per_page  = $_POST['posts_per_page'];

      $args = array('paged' => $paged,
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page);

      $query = new WP_Query($args);

      get_template_part( $loopFile );
    }

    wp_reset_query();

    exit;
   }
```

js

```html
 // AJAX to grab more posts, wrap with a vanilla javascript or
  // jQuery click event function.
  function loadMorePosts(pageNumber, postsPerPage) {
    var query = 'action=load_more&page_no=' + pageNumber + 
        '&loop_file=loop&posts_per_page=' + postsPerPage;

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: query,
        success: function(response){
            // handle response
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried googling this? There are lots of examples of different versions of pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach you can take is to move your query to functions.php and add an action to wp_ajax. For example:

```
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_load_more', 'load_more' );

  function load_more() {
    if ( isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === 'load_more' ){
      $loopFile        = $_POST['loop_file'];
      $paged           = $_POST['page_no'];
      $posts_per_page  = $_POST['posts_per_page'];

      $args = array('paged' => $paged,
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page);

      $query = new WP_Query($args);

      get_template_part( $loopFile );
    }

    wp_reset_query();

    exit;
   }
```

Create a loop.php that resides in the root of your theme.  This will be a template for your posts that can be iterated over:

```
<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
          $query->the_post();
            // populate your post template here
            echo   '<h2>' . get_the_title() .'</h2>';    
        }
?>
```

Place this code in a javascript file. When you need to grab more posts make an AJAX call to the action 'load_more':

```
  // AJAX to grab more posts, wrap with a vanilla javascript or
  // jQuery click event function.
  function loadMorePosts(pageNumber, postsPerPage) {
    var query = 'action=load_more&page_no=' + pageNumber + 
        '&loop_file=loop&posts_per_page=' + postsPerPage;

    $.ajax({
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: query,
        success: function(response){
            // handle response
        }
    });
}
```

This is a very simple implantation, you will want to include a NONCE for security and handle when max number of pages has been reached.

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help Dominique.  I have added the suggested code above, and my website will now not load.  I added my new code to my question.  What did I do wrong?

Comment: I should have been more clear I apologize, the javascript code (the third section) must be in a .js file.  I'm sure you are getting a white screen now, due to PHP errors.  Be sure to have wp_debug: true set in your wp_config.php to view errors.  I also had a typo in the loop.php( I have edited my answer.

Comment: I would also recommend having a basic loop.php file to begin with and then build on it.  So that you can more easily diagnose issues.

Comment: My site is working normally again, thank you.  However, there is still no load more button.  I don't think this code ever added in a button anywhere, what code would I use to do that?

Comment: Thats correct I left that part to you.  The button would be a simple:
`<button id=load-more>load more</button>`
 And in your javascript file listen for the click event and call the function:
 `$('#load-more').click( function() { loadMorePosts(2, 15); });`
I hope this helps!  If this does please upvote my answer or mark it as the accepted answer.  Thanks!